# Convert ObjectNode to Java Object using Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson, dto

I have a json:

```
{
"response": {
    "GeoObjectCollection": {
        "featureMember": [
            {
                "GeoObject": {
                    "description": "Country",
                    "name": "City",
                    "Point": {
                        "pos": "31.992615 45.057626"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "GeoObject": {
                    "description": "Country",
                    "name": "City",
                    "Point": {
                        "pos": "49.242414 49.895935"
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

}

I created DTO:

`GeographicCoordinateDto.java`:

```
@Data
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class GeographicCoordinateDto {
   @JsonProperty("description")
   private String location;
   @JsonProperty("name")
   private String cityName;
   @JsonProperty("Point")
   private GeographicCoordinatesDto geoCoordinates;
}
```

`GeographicCoordinatesDto.java`:

```
@Data
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class GeographicCoordinatesDto {
   @JsonProperty("pos")
   private String geoCoordinates;
}
```

Then I get `JsonNode`:

```
List<JsonNode> responseArrayOfObjects = mapper.readValue(new URL(yandexGeoCoderRestUrl+address), ObjectNode.class).findValues("GeoObject");
```

And I'm trying to convert to my `DTO`:

```
GeographicCoordinatesDto geo = mapper.convertValue(responseArrayOfObjects.get(0), GeographicCoordinatesDto.class);
```

But, I've null object:

```
GeographicCoordinatesDto(geoCoordinates=null)
```

What could be wrong?

**UPDATE:**
`responseArrayOfObjects` contains:

[image]

Comment: I'd check all your `JsonNode`s in the List. There might have been an error reading the JSON?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to get `pos` from the `GeographicCoordinatesDto` object, but it is inside the `Point` object of `GeographicCoordinatesDto`.

You can do this instead:

```
List<JsonNode> responseArrayOfObjects = mapper.readValue(new URL(yandexGeoCoderRestUrl+address), ObjectNode.class).findValues("Point");
```

or create another class for Point:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
class Point {
    @JsonProperty("pos")
    private String geoCoordinates;
}
```

and use it in `GeographicCoordinatesDto`:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
class GeographicCoordinatesDto {
   @JsonProperty("Point")
   private Point point;
}
```

Comment: I made a mistake. Instead `GeographicCoordinateDto.class`, I wrote `GeographicCoordinatesDto.class`